# Assigning a generic List to a concrete ArrayList is causing a compile-time error

Tags: java, generics

I'm struggling to find propper wording for my question (which may be why I was unable to Google it), but it boils down to: why is the line below invalid?

```
List<AbstractInst<? extends IInstType>> insts = new ArrayList<MIPSInst>();
```

I'm getting a compile-time error that `ArrayList<MIPSInst> cannot be converted to List<AbstractInst<? extends IInstType>>`. The class `MIPSInst extends AbstractInst<MIPSInstType>` and `MIPSInstType implements IInstType`.

I've read through the [Oracle documentation on generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html), but I'm clearly missing something key here. A nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You want `List<? extends AbstractInst<? extends IInstType>>` for the data type of `inst`.  I'll post an answer with a detailed explanation if I have time later.

Comment: @DavidWallace: Why would he want the extra wildcard on a variable declaration? Doesn't that make sense only for parameter signatures?

Comment: Those wildcards are to make methods and classes generic, i.e. flexible with regards to types. I don't see why you would want that on a variable declaration.

Comment: @Thilo For this simplified example, it wouldn't be beneficial. When the variable is declared in a parent class then instantiated in a inheritor of that parent, it would be beneficial.

Comment: @Dan: Always better to not simplify the example too much then, I guess. Will delete my answer as it is too close to the question :-)

Comment: @Thilo - Not sure why you deleted your answer.  It looks good to me, and provides valuable information that nobody else has provided (like the problem of inserting into a list whose type parameter is wild).  I will upvote it if you undelete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Earlier today, I thought that you'd want `List<? extends AbstractInst<? extends IInstType>>` to be the data type of `insts`.  It's certainly a data type that will match the object that you're creating, but I doubt whether it's actually what you want in this case.  An explanation is in order.

Suppose you have one class that extends another, like `PrintWriter` extends `Writer`.  That is, every `PrintWriter` is also a `Writer`, but there are extra methods (like `println`) that you can call with a variable of type `PrintWriter`, but not with a variable of type `Writer`.  (I prefer real examples to the standard `Dog extends Animal`).

It's important to understand that `ArrayList<PrintWriter>` is not a subtype of `ArrayList<Writer>`, although intuitively it seems like it might be.  The reason is this.  Suppose I have a variable `myList`, and I write `myList.add(new StringWriter());`  What type could `myList` be?  It clearly can't be of type `ArrayList<PrintWriter>`, because a `StringWriter` is not a `PrintWriter`.  But it *could* be of type `ArrayList<Writer>`, because a `StringWriter` is definitely a `Writer` and therefore must be able to be added to an `ArrayList<Writer>`.

Therefore, any `ArrayList<Writer>` would work OK in the line

```
myList.add(new StringWriter());
```

but any `ArrayList<PrintWriter>` would *not*.  Therefore, an `ArrayList<PrintWriter>` can't possibly be a special type of `ArrayList<Writer>`, in the same sense that a `PrintWriter` is a special type of `Writer`.

To put it another way, it should be possible to write this

```
ArrayList<Writer> myList = new ArrayList<Writer>();
myList.add(new StringWriter());
```

and yet the compiler should somehow prevent us from writing this

```
ArrayList<Writer> myList = new ArrayList<PrintWriter>();
myList.add(new StringWriter());
```

Since the second line is clearly OK, it must be the first line that generates the compile error.  Indeed it is - you can't assign an `ArrayList<PrintWriter>` to a variable of type `ArrayList<Writer>`, because an `ArrayList<PrintWriter>` just *isn't* an `ArrayList<Writer>`.  Or as Jon Skeet expressed it at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2745301/1081110, "Awooga awooga".

For all of that, `ArrayList<Writer>`, `ArrayList<PrintWriter>` and `ArrayList<StringWriter>` all seem a little alike somehow.  It seems there ought to be some type of variable that could refer to any one of these three.  And indeed there is - it's `ArrayList<? extends Writer>`.  But this is an *abstract type*.  You can't instantiate it.  You can't write `new ArrayList<? extends Writer>()` - ultimately an `ArrayList<? extends Writer>` has to actually be either an `ArrayList<Writer>`, an `ArrayList<PrintWriter>` or an `ArrayList<StringWriter>` (or possibly an `ArrayList` of some other type of `Writer`).

This shouldn't be too disturbing to us.  After all, `List<Writer>` is also an abstract type.  You can't write `new List<Writer>()`, because a `List<Writer>` actually has to be either an `ArrayList<Writer>`, or a `LinkedList<Writer>`, or some other type of list of `Writer`.

Also, a variable of type `ArrayList<? extends Writer>` isn't always the most useful variable to have, because you can't use it to add things to the list.  If `myList` is of type `ArrayList<? extends Writer>`, then you can't write `myList.add(myWriter);` no matter what the type of `myWriter` is, because the compiler has no way of checking that `myWriter` is the *right* sort of `Writer` for the list.

What you can do with a variable of type `ArrayList<? extends Writer>` is to get things out of the list.  If `myList` is of type `ArrayList<? extends Writer>`, then you *can* write

```
Writer myWriter = myList.get(0);
```

because no matter whether `myList` refers to an `ArrayList<Writer>`, an `ArrayList<PrintWriter>` or an `ArrayList<StringWriter>`, you know that what's in it is some kind of `Writer`.

So to return to the actual question, where you have

```
List<AbstractInst<? extends IInstType>> insts = new ArrayList<MIPSInst>();
```

which initially seems reasonable, since, as you've explained `MIPSInst` is indeed a subtype of `AbstractInst<? extends IInstType>`.  Or to put it another way, every `MIPSInst` is an `AbstractInst<? extends IInstType>`.

Obviously, you could have written

```
List<MIPSInst> insts = new ArrayList<MIPSInst>();
```

and been able to add things to the list, and get things out of the list.  But you wanted to use some type expression that indicated that any kind of `AbstractInst<? extends IInstType>` is OK, and that you're only going to use this variable for stuff that would work on any kind of `List` of `AbstractInst<? extends IInstType>` objects.

As I have demonstrated with my `StringWriter / PrintWriter` example, the type that you were looking for is `List<? extends AbstractInst<? extends IInstType>>`.  That encapsulates the fact that this list can be a `List` of any type of `AbstractInst<? extends IInstType>`, including `MIPSInst`.

However, unless you cast this variable to something else, using this type will restrict you to a read-only view of the list.  You can `get` things from the list, but you can't `add` anything at all, because the compiler has no way of checking that you're adding the right kind of `AbstractInst<? extends IInstType>`.

In this particular instance, you're creating an empty list.  So it's probably not very useful to have a reference to it that lets you `get` stuff, but not `add` stuff.  So contrary to my earlier comment, it's probably best if you just declare your variable as a `List<MIPSInst>`, then `add` things and `get` things to your heart's content.