# Nested Bounded Wildcard

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

When I try to compile the following code:

```
LinkedList<List<? extends Number>> numList = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>();
```

I get an incompatible type error:

```
Required: LinkedList <java.util.list<? extends java.lang.Number>>
Found: LinkedList <java.util.list<Integer>>
```

How can I achieve having a `LinkedList` which contains elements that are `List`s with elements that extend `Number`?

To be clear, I'm looking to add lists to `numList` in the following fashion:

`numList.add(new LinkedList<Integer>());`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wildcard capture does not go more than one generic level deep.  So while this works:

```
LinkedList<? extends Number> test = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

This does not:

```
LinkedList<List<? extends Number>> numList = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>();
```

The most reasonable explanation I can think of is to think of generics as invariant at the outermost level.  A `LinkedList<List<Integer>>` is not a `LinkedList<List<? extends Number>>`, even though a `List<Integer>` is a `List<? extends Number>`, for the same reason that a `List<Dog>` is not a `List<Animal>` even though a `Dog` is an `Animal`.  Here, `Dog` is to `Animal` as `List<Integer>` is to `List<? extends Number>`.

Well, the Dog/Animal solution is `? extends`:

```
List<? extends Animal> animals = new List<Dog>();
```

Applying the same reasoning, the workaround is another `? extends`:

```
LinkedList<? extends List<? extends Number>> numList = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>();
```

However, you won't be able to add anything to this list because of the first `? extends`. The reference type variable `numList` doesn't know which subtype of `List<? extends Number>` it really is; it could be `ArrayList<Integer>`, so Java cannot provide the type safety that such a thing can be added to such a `LinkedList`. To maintain type safety, the compiler will only allow adding `null`. You'll have to match the generic type parameters exactly, with no wildcards: `LinkedList<List<Integer>> numList = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>();`. You can add a `List<Integer>` to such a `LinkedList`.

Comment: Question, is it possible to do `LinkedList<List<Number>> numList = new LinkedList<List<Number>>();` ?

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'll see if I can find some supporting documentation.

Comment: I actually experimented with this solution.  From here, why doesn't: `numList.add(new LinkedList<Integer>());` work?  I get a `capture<? extends List<? extends Integer> cannot be applied to LinkedList<Integer>`.

Comment: Have a look at my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037561/assigning-a-generic-list-to-a-concrete-arraylist-is-causing-a-compile-time-error/ which is closely related; and at the many answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p which is also related.

Comment: Related - [multiple nested wildcard - arguments not applicable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652718/multiple-nested-wildcard-arguments-not-applicable)

Comment: @rgettman -- Even after the proposed changes I'm still not quite able to achieve what I'm looking to do.  Take a quick look at my comment?

Comment: Yeah, this solution won't let you add anything much to the list.  You will find it hard to work with.  My answer to the question that I linked to explains why.

Comment: You won't be able to `add` anything to this list because of the first `? extends`.  The reference type variable `numList` doesn't know which subtype of `List<? extends Number>` it really is; it could be `ArrayList<Integer>`, so Java cannot provide the type safety that such a thing can be added to such a `LinkedList`.  To maintain type safety, the compiler will only allow adding `null`.  You'll have to match the generic type parameters exactly, with no wildcards: `LinkedList<List<Integer>> numList = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>();`.  You can add a `List<Integer>` to such a `LinkedList`.

Comment: @rgettman, your last comment hits the nail on the head.  Update your actual answer with these details and I'll accept it.

Comment: Added the comment to my answer.