# Using sets of class objects without resorting to raw types

Tags: java, generics, enums

I am trying to implement the visitor pattern via an enum to check to see if a class object is a certain type, and if it is return a certain string. Where I am stuck is trying to create a set of class objects without resorting to raw types. The problem is of course that both `Set` and `Class` are non-reifiable types. I could just go with raw (since thanks to type erasure that is what the compiler is doing anyway) but I wonder if there is a way to do this with generics. Here is what I have (`DateTrackedVersionedEntity` is a super type of `User`):

```
public static enum MissingDataKeyType {

    USER {
        @Override
        public <T extends DateTrackingVersionedEntity> Set<Class<T>> correspondingClasses() {
            return Collections.singleton(User.class);
        }
    }
    //rest of code here

    public abstract <T extends DateTrackingVersionedEntity> Set<Class<T>> correspondingClasses();
}
```

I tried with `?` instead of `T` as well, but no dice - I always get a compiler error about how `Set<Class<User>>` cannot be cast to `Set<Class<T>>`. Is there any way to fix this without raw types?

Apparently, not possible, solved by just ignoring raw types and used `Set<Class<? extends Class>>`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204918/nested-bounded-wildcard

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted to know, closing the question now.

Comment: don't close question`s, defeats the purpose of SO

Comment: Actually closing questions that are duplicates is a feature of SO, when you vote to close you can choose "question was a duplicate of" and enter the SO #

Comment: "solved by just ignoring raw types and used `Set<Class<? extends Class>>`" The only object that is compatible with `Class<? extends Class>` is `Class.class`, because `Class` is the only class that `extends Class`, and `Class` is `final`. You probably want `Set<Class<?>>` instead.