# what does List<? extends SomeClass> mean?

Tags: java, generics, protocol-buffers, covariance, contravariance

I saw that definition in a protobuf generated java file:

```
java.util.List<? extends xxx.yyy.zzz.proto.BasicMessage.DestInfoOrBuilder> foo();
```

But what dose `<?` and `extends` mean?  I can understand `List<SomeClass>` I can't understand `List<? extends SomeClass>`..

Comment: see [java se tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)

Comment: The parameter type should by a subtype of `SomeClass`

Comment: I tried to explain it in my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037561/assigning-a-generic-list-to-a-concrete-arraylist-is-causing-a-compile-time-error

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/java-generics-wildcards) for an explaination of upper bounded and lower bounded wildcards. There are some links to the Java tuts too.

Comment: This will help . http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/28/generics-the-wildcard-operator/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [generic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_generics) declaration.

It is used to check types at compile time. You could put any object into a list, but that would make it more difficult to maintain and could cause `ClassCastException`s, if not used appropriate.

`<? extends xxx.yyy.zzz.proto.BasicMessage.DestInfoOrBuilder>` means *"allow every class which extends `DestInfoOrBuilder`"*.

Answer (score 13):

In java generics programing, there are two kinds of bounds when using wildcards.

1)Upper Bounded Wildcards .
like: `ArrayList <? extends Number> p`, it means you can use anything extends Number to fill the ArrayList.

2)Lower Bounded Wildcards.
like:`ArrayList<? super Integer> list`,
it means you will have to pass anything which is in the super class (such as Number, Object)of Integer to fill the ArrayList.

for more information, refer to [wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).

Answer (score 2):

In `java generic code`, the question mark **(?)**, called the **wildcard**, represents an **unknown type**. The wildcard can be used in a variety of situations: as the type of a parameter, field, or local variable; sometimes as a return type (though it is better programming practice to be more specific). The wildcard is never used as a type argument for a generic method invocation, a generic class instance creation, or a supertype.

For more information read [Java Generic's Wildcards](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-generics/wildcards.html) and [Generics: The wildcard operator](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/28/generics-the-wildcard-operator/)