# Set not applicable for Collection in generic method with Java

Tags: java, generics, set, generic-collections

I defined a generic function in java with the signature

`<V> List<V> sortedValuesFromMap(Map<?, Collection<V>> keysValues, Comparator<V> comp)`

which takes a Map mapping any type of keys to a Collection of some defined type V, and a comparator of type V. The method works great and the Java compiler does not complain about type incompatibility.

But now when I want to apply this method to a map of the type `Map<String, Set<String>>` and the `AlphanumComparator` (see [here](http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html)) the compiler says :

> The method `sortedValuesFromMap(Map<?,Collection<V>>, Comparator<V>)`
>   in the type MyUtils is not applicable for the arguments
>   (`Map<String,Set<String>, AlphanumComparator`)

Turning `Collection` to `Set` in the signature of `sortedValuesFromMap` would fix it – but I do not want to do that. So why is Java forcing me to do so, although `Set<E>` is [implementing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) `Collection<E>`?

PS: If someone is interested in my code:

```
public static <V> List<V> sortedValuesFromMap(Map<?, Collection<V>> keysValues,
        Comparator<V> comp) {
    List<V> values = new LinkedList<V>();
    for (Collection<V> col : keysValues.values()) {
        values.addAll(col);
    }
    Collections.sort(values, comp);
    return values;
}
```

Comment: Change `Map<?, Collection<V>>` to `Map<?, ? extends Collection<V>>`

Comment: @DavidWallace Very fast and very great. Thank you so much! Could you explain why mine is wrong?

Comment: Sure, I just thought I'd give you the key piece of information before typing up my answer.  I cover this issue in a lot more detail at http://stackoverflow.com/q/20037561/1081110 if you're interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as a [`List<Dog>` is not a `List<Animal>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p), a `Map<String, Set<String>>` is not a `Map<String, Collection<String>>` and it's not a `Map<?, Collection<String>>`.

The solution here is to add a wildcard in place of `Set` to allow a subclass in the generic type parameter.

```
//                                                   Add v
public static <V> List<V> sortedValuesFromMap(Map<?, ? extends Collection<V>> keysValues,
    Comparator<V> comp) {
```

Comment: Thanks, that explanation and the linked article helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `Map<String,Set<V>>` is not a subtype of `Map<String,Collection<V>>`.  Think about what type `x` can be, if it's legal to write `x.put("Hello",new ArrayList<V>());`

In this case, `x` could be a  `Map<String,Collection<V>>`, since an `ArrayList<V>` is certainly a `Collection<V>`.  But it couldn't be a `Map<String,Set<V>>`, since an `ArrayList<V>` is not a `Set<V>`.  Therefore it's untrue to say that any `Map<String,Set<V>>` "is a" `Map<String,Collection<V>>`.

The type that you want is either `Map<String,? extends Collection<V>>` or `Map<?,? extends Collection<V>>`.  Both `Map<String,Set<V>>` and `Map<String,Collection<V>>` are subtypes of these types.