# Java: Same name but different generic type

Tags: java, generics, types

I wanna use an ArrayList for my Code but it should contain different types of Objects.
So it should be sth like this:

```
 switch (foo) {
        case "foo1":
            list=new ArrayList<foo1>();
            break;
        case "foo2":
            list = new ArrayList<foo2>();
            break;
```

I know the posted Code does not work but is it possible to make sth similar.

And before you ask there should be multiple actions performed on this List but i dont wont to write everything again just with a different name for the List.

```
public class foo1 {}

public class foo2 {}

    import java.util.ArrayList;
public class work{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<?> list;
     switch (args[0]) {
            case "foo1":
                list=new ArrayList<foo1>();
                break;
            case "foo2":
                 list= new ArrayList<foo2>();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Some Error Text");
                return;

        }
     list.add(new foo1());
    }
}
```

Comment: It is possible, but probably not very useful. It looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you describe how would you like to use reference to such lists?

Comment: the posted code will work in Java 7

Comment: If `list` is defined outside of your `switch` as `List<?> list`, I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're asking for is **entirely pointless** because of type erasure.  Type parameters cease to exist at run time, so the thing you get from `new ArrayList<Foo1>` is exactly the same as the thing you get from `new ArrayList<Foo2>`.

In other words, type parameters are information for the compiler only.  And with the code that you're working with, the compiler really only cares about the declared type of `list`, not the type that you supply when you instantiate it.

Of course, your code will compile if you've declared

```
ArrayList<?> list;
```

or

```
List<?> list;
```

or you can narrow it down if `Foo1` and `Foo2` have a common supertype (other than `Object`) - say they are both subtypes of `Foo`, you can write

```
List<? extends Foo> list;
```

but why would you bother?

Comment: Thank you that worked, but now i cant use the methodes from ArrayList.
I get a "incompatible types: ArrayList<CAP#1> can not be converted to ArrayList<Foo>...". Do i have to cast it to the right type everytime?

Comment: Can you give an example of a line of code that gives you that error?

Comment: So i created a List with the wildcard and intialized it with different generic types in a switch case but when i want to use something like
fooList.add(foo1);
it gives me the error with <CAP#1>.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean.  Can you edit the code into the question so that I can see it, and maybe try to reproduce it in my own IDE?

Comment: i added a short part but it should reproduce my problem.

Comment: Yeah, I see the problem.  Basically, when you do an `add`, the compiler wants to check that you're adding the right type of object, but it has no way of doing that.  This is closely related to the issue that I answered at http://stackoverflow.com/q/20037561/1081110 and there isn't an easy answer.  Is there any way you can design this differently?